# Can HP SmartArray P800 be used with 3Tb drives?

Tags: hp-smart-array

I can get a good deal on a used card, but wish to use larger disks with it. The card has LSI's SAS1078 chip. Can it use 3Tb drives to their full potential, or will they appear smaller?

Searching online I get somewhat conflicting information. If it matters, I do not care for RAID-capabilities as I intend to use ZFS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the HP Smart Array P800 can accommodate 2TB+ disks. No, it will not be helpful to you as a ZFS controller. There's no way to bypass the RAID functionality.

If you want something for ZFS-only, try a standard LSI SAS HBA without RAID features; e.g. [LSI 9211-8i](http://www.lsi.com/products/host-bus-adapters/pages/lsi-sas-9211-8i.aspx)

Comment: Good point regarding not being able to bypass the RAID configuration in a P800

Answer (score 1):

This official HP document indicates that there is a 3TB drive that is compatible with P800 array controller.

http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04136952.pdf?ver=27

Top of page 13 or search for 3tb.

I would not deviate from the part number recommendation regarding their HCL.